# Finding and updating field in nested dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, find

I have a dict like so:

```
mobs = {
    'world': {
        0: {'mID': 255, 'xPos': 29, 'yPos': 45}
        1: {'mID': 784, 'xPos': 34, 'yPos': 84}
        }, 
    'village': {
        0: {'mID': 256, 'xPos': 77, 'yPos': 25}
        1: {'mID': 67, 'xPos': 92, 'yPos': 16}
        2: {'mID': 998, 'xPos': 8, 'yPos': 5}
        }, 
    }
```

I want to increment the `xPos` where `mID` = x in the 'world' dict, but not sure how to point to it

Do I have to loop through each record in `world` and check `if mID = x`, or is there a quicker way?

(updated)

```
x = 784
for row in mobs['world']:
    if mobs['world'][row]['ID'] == x:
        mobs['world'][row]['xPos'] -= 1
```

Comment: Maybe you should rearrange the structure. The middle dictionary look more like a list and if you access the items via `mID` it could be a good dictionary key.

Comment: yes, you have to loop through if you do not want to re-construct the `dictionary` but the code you have for that task will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your change apply only to `world` sub-dict, you can do:

```
x = 784
for key, value in mobs['world'].items():
    if value['mID'] == x:
        mobs['world'][key]['xPos'] += 1
```

**Output:**

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>>
>>> mobs = {
...     'world': {
...         0: {'mID': 255, 'xPos': 29, 'yPos': 45},
...         1: {'mID': 784, 'xPos': 34, 'yPos': 84}
...     },
...     'village': {
...         0: {'mID': 256, 'xPos': 77, 'yPos': 25},
...         1: {'mID': 67, 'xPos': 92, 'yPos': 16},
...         2: {'mID': 998, 'xPos': 8, 'yPos': 5}
...     },
... }
>>>
>>> x = 784
>>> for key, value in mobs['world'].items():
...     if value['mID'] == x:
...         mobs['world'][key]['xPos'] += 1
...
>>> pprint(mobs)
{'village': {0: {'mID': 256, 'xPos': 77, 'yPos': 25},
             1: {'mID': 67, 'xPos': 92, 'yPos': 16},
             2: {'mID': 998, 'xPos': 8, 'yPos': 5}},
 'world': {0: {'mID': 255, 'xPos': 29, 'yPos': 45},
           1: {'mID': 784, 'xPos': 35, 'yPos': 84}}}
```

Comment: In this answer, the code to increment `xPos` is a little more complicated than it needs to be; the code already has the dictionary in `value`, so why not simply do `value['xPos'] += 1`?

Answer (score 0):

Using your given data structure you will need to iterate over the dictionaries in order to test the `mID` and increment the `xPos`. The dictionaries can be updated in place using this simple code:

```
x = 784

for mob in mobs['world'].values():
    if mob['mID'] == x:
        mob['xPos'] += 1
```

This iterates over the *values* of the dictionaries contained in `mobs['world']`, compares the `mID` against the target value, and increments `xPos` when there is a match. The increment is effective because dictionaries are mutable.